# C chord - Fret Dependency

Tags: chord-theory, ukulele

Traditionally, the C chord is shown on a ukuele as the first string, third fret. However, the third string played open is also a C. Could this be thought of as C just being played in a different octave or is it a different concept?

Comment: Could be a dupe - there was a question a couple of weeks ago about notes on a guitar chord D.

Answer (score 3):

The concept is called *doubling*.  You can double a note as many times as you'd like and it won't change the name of the chord.

Because a ukulele has just four strings you can only have one doubling for a triad like C major.  But it doesn't have to be the C that's doubled: you could double the E by fretting 0-0-0-7 or double the G by fretting 0-0-0-10 and it's still going to be a C major.  The different combinations are different *voicings* (ways to play the chord tones) but it's always going to be the same chord.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the standard fingering for C major on the uke uses three open strings (G, C and E) and one fingered string (the A string fretted up to C).  We get C twice, and the open C on the third string will sound an octave lower than the fingered one on the first string.  It all adds up to a C major chord.  And so would any other fingering that produced the pitch set C, E, G in any order, in any octave.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

it doubles the C, sure, but it also *PREVENTS an A from being sounded* which is the real reason for doubling the C in the first place